# remove object after collision

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have two objects `troll` and `pig`. I'm detecting collisions between these two characters with Pygame's `colliderect` function. collisions for this works perfectly, however I am unable to remove the object from the screen when a collision occurs. When a `troll` `collideswith` a `pig`, I want the pig to disappear from the screen. I set an image for both of these and bit them, is there a way to un-blit? Ive tried `pygame.image.set_alpha(255)` (which set full transparency of an image) function to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just stop drawing the pig? Each frame you fill the screen with the background, so it won't be visible.

Comment: what about the other objects, they will be removed too

Comment: @Pro-grammer by not drawing the pig? could you paste your drawing code?